# Writing a GET functionality for json-like data in Python

Tags: python, json, algorithm

I am working on a coding challenge for self-development and I came across a question where I am given an input like this:

```
add {"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}
add {"id":2,"last":"Doe","first":"Jane","location":{"city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","postalCode":"94105"},"active":true}
add {"id":3,"last":"Black","first":"Jim","location":{"city":"Spokane","state":"WA","postalCode":"99207"},"active":true}
add {"id":4,"last":"Frost","first":"Jack","location":{"city":"Seattle","state":"WA","postalCode":"98204"},"active":false}
get {"location":{"state":"WA"},"active":true}
get {"id":1}
get {"active":true}
delete {"active":true}
get {}
```

And what I am doing is adding the entries that start with `add` to a list called `database = []`:

```
json_input = []
database = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    json_input.append(line.split("', "))

for i in range(0, len(json_input)):
    if json_input[i][0] == 'add':
        database.append(json_input[i][1])
```

What I want to do is to print out every entry that matches what follows `get` and delete every entry that matches what follows `delete`. This is where I am stuck. Currently, this is what `json_input()` looks like. `database` is empty:

```
[
['add {"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}\n'], 
['add {"id":2,"last":"Doe","first":"Jane","location":{"city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","postalCode":"94105"},"active":true}\n'], 
['add {"id":3,"last":"Black","first":"Jim","location":{"city":"Spokane","state":"WA","postalCode":"99207"},"active":true}\n'], 
['add {"id":4,"last":"Frost","first":"Jack","location":{"city":"Seattle","state":"WA","postalCode":"98204"},"active":false}\n'], 
['get {"location":{"state":"WA"},"active":true}\n'], ['get {"id":1}\n'], 
['get {"active":true}\n'], ['delete {"active":true}\n'], 
['get {}']
]
```

Comment: [Where do I start]( https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start) is not a valid question here; it is not focused enough.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `json_input` - you should directly run code which `add`, `get`  or `delete` data. You should do all in one `for`-loop.

Comment: you have normal `dictionary` in your `JSON` so `database` should be `dictionary` instead of `list`

Comment: you should use module `json` to convert your `JSON` to normal `dictionary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an easy-to-read way to handle this would be a simple class that maintains a list of records. You can add methods for the various commands you want to handle. Then it's just a matter of defining the methods and processing the input to pass to the methods. Here's a possible way (without any frills like error checking):

```
import json

raw_data = '''add {"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}
add {"id":2,"last":"Doe","first":"Jane","location":{"city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","postalCode":"94105"},"active":true}
add {"id":3,"last":"Black","first":"Jim","location":{"city":"Spokane","state":"WA","postalCode":"99207"},"active":true}
add {"id":4,"last":"Frost","first":"Jack","location":{"city":"Seattle","state":"WA","postalCode":"98204"},"active":false}
get {"location":{"state":"WA"},"active":true}
get {"id":1}
get {"active":true}
delete {"active":true}
get {}'''

class Data:
    @staticmethod
    def matches(obj, query):
        if not isinstance(query, dict):
            return obj == query
        return all(Data.matches(obj.get(key), q) for key, q in query.items())                
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def add(self, record):
        self.data.append(record)

    def get(self, query):
        for item in self.data:
            if (Data.matches(item, query)):
                print(item)
    
    def delete(self, query):
        self.data = [record for record in self.data if not Data.matches(record, query)]


data = Data()

for line in raw_data.split('\n'):
    command, line = line.split(None, 1)
    command = getattr(data, command)
    command(json.loads(line))
```

This will print the records from `WA` then the `active:True` records. Then after deleting the `True` records it will print everything (the result of the `{}` query), which is the only one left -- the `active:False` record:

```
{'id': 3, 'last': 'Black', 'first': 'Jim', 'location': {'city': 'Spokane', 'state': 'WA', 'postalCode': '99207'}, 'active': True}
{'id': 1, 'last': 'Doe', 'first': 'John', 'location': {'city': 'Oakland', 'state': 'CA', 'postalCode': '94607'}, 'active': True}
{'id': 1, 'last': 'Doe', 'first': 'John', 'location': {'city': 'Oakland', 'state': 'CA', 'postalCode': '94607'}, 'active': True}
{'id': 2, 'last': 'Doe', 'first': 'Jane', 'location': {'city': 'San Francisco', 'state': 'CA', 'postalCode': '94105'}, 'active': True}
{'id': 3, 'last': 'Black', 'first': 'Jim', 'location': {'city': 'Spokane', 'state': 'WA', 'postalCode': '99207'}, 'active': True}
{'id': 4, 'last': 'Frost', 'first': 'Jack', 'location': {'city': 'Seattle', 'state': 'WA', 'postalCode': '98204'}, 'active': False}
```

If this were a test or a serious coding challenge, you would probably want to look carefully at `matches()` to make sure it properly handles edge cases (I didn't do that).